# The shortest path to catch number 2 in 2d matrix

Tags: javascript

From the position in the matrix where `1` is placed I need to find the number of spaces (`up, left, right, down`) that you must move to reach `2`. Also you can wrap around one side of the matrix to the other. So the example below should return 2, cause a 1 needs to move to the left first and then down. I am completely stuck.

```js
var ARR = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  ONE, TWO;

for (x in ARR) {
  for (y in ARR[x]) {
    if (ARR[x][y] == 1) {
      ONE = [x, y];
    }
    if (ARR[x][y] == 2) {
      TWO = [x, y];
    }
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = Math.abs(ONE[0] - TWO[0]) - Math.abs(ONE[1] - TWO[1]);
```

Comment: I am not exactly getting what do you mean by returning 2 spaces in this argument . Shouldn't it return 4 as  the number 1 will have  to move 3 rights and 1 down to reach the number 2 ?

Comment: @UchihaItachi it can also move to the other side of the matrix. Just follow this path for a 1 - left and down. It will appear on the right and get down

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you first work out the steps you need to move right, then the steps down, it gets easier:

```
var ARR = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  ONE, TWO;

for (x in ARR) {
  for (y in ARR[x]) {
    if (ARR[x][y] == 1) {
      ONE = [x, y];
    }
    if (ARR[x][y] == 2) {
      TWO = [x, y];
    }
  }
}

var xSteps = Math.abs(ONE[0] - TWO[0]);
if (xSteps === 3) // then you can also do it in one by going the other direction
{
    xSteps = 1;
}

var ySteps = Math.abs(ONE[1] - TWO[1]);
if (ySteps === 3) // then you can also do it in one by going the other direction
{
    ySteps = 1;
}


document.body.innerHTML = "X steps: " + xSteps + ", Y steps: " + ySteps + ", total steps:" + (xSteps + ySteps);
```

If your matrix size is variable, not always 4 x 4, then the hard-coded check for 3 needs to be changed to (half the matrix size + 1)...

Comment: This won't necessarily generate the desired results for something larger, like say a width of `10` - you need to change the logic to something like `xSteps = ARR[0].length - xSteps`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below solution.In this solution, no need to hardcode any values. simply you can change your matrix

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dwij/2v3z7q23/1/) is the fiddle to play around.

```js
var ARR = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  ONE, TWO;

for (x in ARR) {
  for (y in ARR[x]) {
    if (ARR[x][y] == 1) {
      ONE = [x, y];
    }
    if (ARR[x][y] == 2) {
      TWO = [x, y];
    }
  }
}

var width = ARR[0].length;
var height = ARR.length;

//get two methods of reaching via y axis
var upDown1 = Math.abs(ONE[0] - TWO[0]);
var upDown2 = height - Math.abs(ONE[0] - TWO[0]);

//get two methods of reaching via x axis
var leftRight1 = Math.abs(ONE[1] - TWO[1]);
var leftRight2 = width - Math.abs(ONE[1] - TWO[1]);

//get the minimum space counts of above methods in y and x axis
var minUpDown = Math.min(upDown1,upDown2);
var minLeftRight = Math.min(leftRight1,leftRight2);

 
document.body.innerHTML = minUpDown+minLeftRight;
```

Comment: I think it was your `arr` variable that was the problem, I ran your code before you edited your post. Sorry, will remove the comments now.

Comment: ok np, I have added a jsFiddle link so anyone can play around the solution.
Feel free to find any edge cases which my solution fails

Answer (score 0):

You're saying in the question introduction that the board itself "wrapped around" - i.e. you can go to the left of the leftmost edge and end up on the right, but you're not including that in your logic, since you're only checking for the distance without considering wrapping.

Here is a valid solution:

```js
// Constants for the array, as well as the
// width and height of the array
const arr = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
const width = arr[0].length,
      height = arr.length;

// Stores the position of the "1" and "2"
let one, two;
// Horizontal and vertical distances between
// the "1" and "2"
let dist_x, dist_y;

// Figure out where the "1" and "2" is
for (let x in arr) {
  for (let y in arr[x]) {
    if (arr[x][y] === 1) {
      one = [x, y];
    } else if (arr[x][y] === 2) {
      two = [x, y];
    }
  } 
}

// Sets the horizontal and vertical distances
// between the two numbers
dist_x = Math.abs(one[1] - two[1]);
dist_y = Math.abs(one[0] - two[0]);

// If the distance is longer than half the size of
// the board in either direction, we go the other way
// instead.
if (dist_x > width / 2) {
  dist_x = width - dist_x;
}

if (dist_y > height / 2) {
  dist_y = height - dist_y;
}

console.log(dist_x + dist_y);
```

Comment: This solution fails when we change the matrix dimensions. For ex-:
`const arr = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0 ,0]
];`

Comment: @dwij Fixed the program!